# How to load data from ajax to Chosen Jquery?

Tags: jquery, ajax, html, jquery-chosen

I found more time about this but seem it's not have answer.

```
   $(".cb_bu_info").chosen({
            source: function () {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "../BUS/WebService.asmx/LIST_BU",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function (data) {
                        $("#cb_bu_info").html('');
                        $.each($.parseJSON(data.d), function (idx, obj) {
                            $("#cb_bu_info").append('<option value="' + obj.BU_ID + '">' + obj.BU_NAME + '</option>');
                        });
                        $("#cb_bu_info").trigger("liszt:updated");
                    },
                    error: function (data) {
                        console.log(data.d);
                    }
                });
            }
        });
```

I run it , when i see browser dev tools, no error but it's not working , no show data in select .If you have a idea about issue, plz give me some adviced. Thank you

Comment: don't need `$.parseJSON` when `dataType` is set to json, `data` will already be an object

Comment: It's not working .`$.each(data, function (idx, obj) {`

Comment: any errors? is success handler being triggered? `not working` isn't much detail when browser dev tools has a full suite of debugging information available

Comment: Yub, when i browser dev tools,I no see error.I don't understand "Why it not working? . I test ajax `LIST_BU` , It have data @@ What's the problem in here ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this  [chosen-ajax-addition](https://github.com/ksykulev/chosen-ajax-addition)

it's a Plugin For Chosen